# Substituting values of variables in solution of a system of linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, variable

After solving a system of 21 linear equations in 21 variables (called `Xi` in my code) I got the values for all the 21 variables, in the following way:

```
{X21 -> 2./q^2, 
 X20 -> (2. - n q X21)/(m q), 
 X19 -> (2. - m n X20 - n (m X20 + n X21))/m^2, 
 X18 -> 2./(l q), 
 X17 -> (2. - l n X18)/(l m), 
 X16 -> 2./l^2, 
 X15 -> (2. - g q X18)/(f q), 
 X14 -> (2. - f n X15 - g (m X17 + n X18))/(f m), 
 X13 -> (2. - g l X16)/(f l), 
 X12 -> (2. - f g X13 - g (f X13 + g X16))/f^2, 
 X11 -> 2./(e q), 
 X10 -> (2. - e n X11)/(e m), 
 X9 -> 2./(e l), 
 X8 -> (2. - e g X9)/(e f), 
 X7 -> 2./e^2, 
 X6 -> (2. - b q X11)/(a q), 
 X5 -> (2. - b (m X10 + n X11) - a n X6)/(a m), 
 X4 -> (2. - b l X9)/(a l), 
 X3 -> (2. - a g X4 - b (f X8 + g X9))/(a f), 
 X2 -> (2. - b e X7)/(a e), 
 X1 -> (2. - a b X2 - b (a X2 + b X7))/a^2}
```

The latin letters `a,b..q` are only to be considered as constant parameters. What I would like to do is to express EACH and EVERY value of the variables as a function of only letters. This is possible, because each `Xi` variable depends on ONLY the variables from X21 to `Xi`, therefore in principle the problem boils down to a simple substitution.

Nevertheless, I find it difficult to operate this massive substitution in a concise and elegant way, which eventually should produce an array where each entry is given by the value of one variable `Xi`, expressed in terms of `a,b,...q`.

Comment: "solving a system of 21 linear equations in 21 variables" - I'm either going blind, or you only have 13 solutions.

Comment: @J.M.they are indeed 21. I edited my post to make it clearer

Comment: `Solve[Equal @@@ list, First /@ list]` should do the trick.

Comment: As a minor  change to @J.M. answer: "Solve[Equal @@@ (list // Rationalize), First /@ list] // Simplify"

Comment: @J.M. and **Bob Hanlon**. I know I am not supposed to do this but +1, these are really great answers!

Comment: @Bob, if you want, you can post your improvement as a bonafide answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {X21 -> 2./q^2, X20 -> (2. - n q X21)/(m q), 
   X19 -> (2. - m n X20 - n (m X20 + n X21))/m^2, X18 -> 2./(l q), 
   X17 -> (2. - l n X18)/(l m), X16 -> 2./l^2, X15 -> (2. - g q X18)/(f q), 
   X14 -> (2. - f n X15 - g (m X17 + n X18))/(f m), 
   X13 -> (2. - g l X16)/(f l), X12 -> (2. - f g X13 - g (f X13 + g X16))/f^2,
    X11 -> 2./(e q), X10 -> (2. - e n X11)/(e m), X9 -> 2./(e l), 
   X8 -> (2. - e g X9)/(e f), X7 -> 2./e^2, X6 -> (2. - b q X11)/(a q), 
   X5 -> (2. - b (m X10 + n X11) - a n X6)/(a m), X4 -> (2. - b l X9)/(a l), 
   X3 -> (2. - a g X4 - b (f X8 + g X9))/(a f), X2 -> (2. - b e X7)/(a e), 
   X1 -> (2. - a b X2 - b (a X2 + b X7))/a^2};
```

Starting with J.M.'s comment

```
Solve[Equal @@@ list, First /@ list] // Simplify
```

[image]

The result is cleaner if the numeric values are rationalized

```
Solve[Equal @@@ (list // Rationalize), First /@ list] // Simplify
```

[image]